# How to make a flex item fill empty space under another adjacent flex item (wrapping)

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to make a flex item stretch under another shorter adjacent flex item so it will fill any empty space.

In the following code pen the 'first-item' (green background) should fill the space under the second item (pink background).

here is the code pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKaygK

and here is the code:

html

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='first-item'>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some more text</div>
    <div>some more text again</div>
  </div>
  <div class='second-item'>some box</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap; not working*/
}

.first-item {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.second-item {
  align-self: baseline;
  background: pink; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to rely on the *old* float technique to achieve this:

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

.first-item {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.second-item {
  background: pink; 
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  
  <div class='second-item'>some box</div>
  <div class='first-item'>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some more text</div>
    <div>some more text again</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if You add a third item can do the desire result, which in fact is the second wrap that contains the first and the second item. This seems to imply that if you put a flex container inside another flex container that the inner flex container would also implicitly become a flex item for its containing flex container even if this is not explicitly defined.

```css
.first-wrap {
  display: flex;
  
/*   flex-wrap: nowrap; */
}

.second-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.first-item {
  background: lightgreen;
  
}

.second-item {
  align-self: baseline;
  background: pink;
}


.second-wrap {
 background: lightgreen;
 }
```

```html
<div class='first-wrap'>
  <div class='second-wrap'>
  <div class='first-item'>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some more text</div>
    <div>some more text again</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='second-item'>some box</div>
  <div>
</div>
```